# WPF menu closes on mouseup when window open from excel add-in project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, excel-addins

I have a problem when creating a menu in WPF. What happens is that it closes automatically when you stop pressing the mouse button. I want it to behave as regular menu's where you can click and the subitems will stay up but I can't find anyway to get this done.

The code looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ExcelAddIn.MyWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <Grid>
            <DockPanel>
                <Menu Width="Auto" IsMainMenu="True" >
                    <MenuItem Header="Item">
                        <MenuItem Header="SubItem" />
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with logical focus maybe? I saw something about it might being a bug in .NET framwork? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

I didn't think it made any difference at first but obviously it does. When running the code in a standalone WPF application it works, however when I try to open the WPF window from a Excel-addin project I get this problem..

Comment: Your menu works as expected. You click on menu header and it opens sub menu. You click anywhere else and it closes sub menu. How do you want it to work?

Comment: I'm not clear enough sorry. What I mean is that when I hold down the mouse button everything works as it should. However if I click a menuitem(mousedown+up) I want to menu to open(as usually) however it closes on mouseup even if I stay on the menuitem. Do you understand?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. However it still works for me as you want to have it work you. So it should be other stuff in your window or code.

Comment: you are right, I edited my question now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I solved the problem. Turns out it was a focus problem after all.
When the excel addin executed the WPF window the excel window was still in focus. So on every mouseup the focus would jump back from WPF to excel.

All I had to do was change the execution from this:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.Activate();
mainWindow.Show();
```

to this:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.Activate();
mainWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Thanks for help anyway guys!

Comment: This is a focus problem with recommended solutions. See my answer to a related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/8412768/233095

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your code a tiny bit (`DockPanel.Dock="Top"` and an extra grid to fill the rest of the dock panel). It works fine and the menu stays open. Does it work for you?:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu Width="Auto"
                  IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="Item">
                    <MenuItem Header="SubItem" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <Grid />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It is not clear if it is the code that is causing the problem or the way something else. If you make a minimal add-in (no code other than needed), does it still have this problem?

Comment: I have to projects in my solution, one excel addin and one WPF. When I make WPF the startup it works fine, problem just arise when I make the excel addin execute the WPF.